# getting extra "\" with JSON object when submitted

Tags: jquery, json

```
Parameters: {"celebration"=>{"friend_details"=>"[{\"name\":\"Mitchell Gould\",\"fbuid\":\"751640040\",\"picUrl\":\"http://graph.facebook.com/751640040/picture\",\"birthday\":\"10/07/1967\"},{\"name\":\"Anthony Rosenfeld\",\"fbuid\":\"692130342\",\"picUrl\":\"http://graph.facebook.com/692130342/picture\",\"birthday\":\"12/09\"}]", "manager_details"=>"[{\"name\":\"Mitchell Gould\",\"fbuid\":\"751640040\",\"picUrl\":\"http://graph.facebook.com/751640040/picture\",\"birthday\":\"10/07/1967\"}]"}}
```

I seem to be getting these "\" with the submitted values. How can stop them from being added to my object.

Here is how I make the object:

```
json_details.push({name: fb.name, fbuid: fb.id, picUrl: pic_url, birthday: fb.birthday });
var friend_details = JSON.stringify(json_details);
```

Then I pass this in with the form as a hidden field:

```
html += "<input type='hidden' id='manager' value='"+manager_details +"'  name='celebration[manager_details]' />"
```

Comment: Is your php enabled with magic_quotes_gpc ?

Comment: The backslashes may be an artifact of the way you're printing out the data. What are you using to display the "`Parameters: ...`" bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that you "stringify" the "details" and then further embed that in your request string. When you do that, the "stringified" JSON will be regarded as a simple character string, the surrounding quotes you see will be added, and any quotes in it will be escaped.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. I guess I just need to embed it somehow then instead of stringifying it. So the problem is that when I don't do JSON.stringify(json_details) I get an array of [object Object]

Comment: If you control the other end you can un-escape the transmitted string somehow.

Comment: One thing that's unclear is the `"=>{"` characters.  That's not JSON notation, but some sort of pseudo-JSON encoding.  Makes it harder to figure out a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're double-json-ifying your data.

You don't show how you get from `friend_details` to `manager_details` but from what you have shown, I'd say you're creating a `manager_details` object whose `friend_details` key points to the json-ified string and then you're converting the whole `manager_details` object to JSON. From at least what you've shown, you just want to assign the `json_details` object to the `friend_details` key in `manager_details`.